# How do I get a test user in Facebook to login to my app so I could get the authorization code to exchange for access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I would like to do this to test the whole use-case in my app of which a user would submit the authorization code. How can I do this for a test user created by my app? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the button to log-in as the test user, or use the `login_url` parameter when you access the test user in the API (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ ) - once logged in to facebook, use your app as normal

Comment: i would like it to be entirely automated. meaning no clicking, as it is a unit test.

Comment: Like I said, you get a login URL for the test users in the API, any browser testing framework should be usable once you use that URL for the login